# How can I left align text under a centered button?

Tags: html, css

How can I left align help text under a button? The desired functionality is for the help container text to left align with the left side of the button

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tttcdgu9/)

```
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
     Login with Google
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="help-container">
    <ul>
      <li>Because it's easier</li>
      <li>Never forget your password!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

.button-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried making the width of the button the size of the parent div but that isn't my desired outcome. I've also tried adding a div around both the `.button-container` and `.help-container` but it takes the width of the parent div

Comment: .help-container {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:200px;
}

Comment: @floor that assumes a width

Comment: Is the width of `Login with Google` button fixed?

Comment: @5aledmaged preferably not

Comment: use flex attribute `.container{display: flex}`

Comment: @StevenDiaz can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution using flexbox

CSS:

```
.container {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items : center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Login with Google
    </button>
    <ul>
      <li>Because it's easier</li>
      <li>Never forget your password!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tttcdgu9/2/)

Comment: .help-container should be taken off the flow to let button at center ;)  https://jsfiddle.net/pyjkfxwx/5/

Answer (score 2):

You can put the help-container *into* the button container and use this CSS:

```
.button-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.help-container {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pyjkfxwx/1/